# Percentage calculation from infopath to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I am a newbie in sharepoint/infopath. 
I am trying to edit an existing field in sharepoint which seems to be loaded from infopath.

The flow of the program is as follows:

I open a form (which is integrated using infopath) from sharepoint. The form has some multiple choice questions and at the end there is a submit button. After clicking "submit", I am transferred to a list view which displays the "number of correct answers" and "your percentage" columns (I can have multiple attempts and they are displayed in the list).

I am trying to edit the calculations of the percentage. When I open the infopath form, I can see that there is a field called "Your percentage". I displayed the setting and there is no formula.

Where can I edit that field?

Thanks!

Comment: remember to open form in designer mode, and then show all fields

Comment: I did show all the fields, and I have a field called percentage. But there is not function associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the button Rule Inspector to check all the rules cotained on the form, the button is located on the data ribbon:

[image: Infopath RuleInspector]

There you can see all the rules, just look up for the one that calculates the percentage.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no rule about the percentage.. Any idea where else to look?

Comment: Can you export the rule inspector to a pdf and share? meanwhile check if there is a calculated field on the sharepoint list.